# Let Emacs highlight syntax keyword pair

Tags: c++, emacs

I am learning how to use Emacs to write code (c++). I was wondering, if there a package (I am using Emacs 24.3) that can highlight syntax elements which are pair or belong to the same group? For example, I would like three elements `if`, `elseif`, `else` to be highlighted at the same time when the cursor is on any of them, so that I can see clearly which three blocks of code belong to the same condition sentence. I think it is useful especially when there is nesting `if` sentences. Another scenario would be (I am not sure if it is the same feature as previous one), when the cursor is on a `return` key word, all `return` keywords will be highlighted at the same time. That way I can check all the exiting cases in a function.

BTW this feature might be less useful in c++ than in some other languages such as shell scripting or VB.NET, where there is no curly bracket. But it is still a good helper in reading the code.

Comment: For the returns to be highlighted *(like for any word on which the cursor currently is )* you could use `highlight-symbol-mode` from the [Highlight symbol](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSymbol).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such a thing already for C++.  For languages whose major modes uses SMIE for navigation and indentation (e.g. ruby-mode), you can enable `show-paren-mode` which will highlight the matching opening/closing keyword.  If you're on the "if" it won't highlight the else/elseif, tho.

And I don't know any package which higlights all the "return"s in a function, although this should be fairly easy to write based on `beginning-of-defun` and `end-of-defun`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel the same about highlighting the `return`, I think I am able to do it myself. But for grouped keywords, "if...elseif...else", or "switch...case...default",there is no way of highlighting them? Well, maybe `switch` is not a good example since it is not that useful. But for (nesting) `if`, highlighting keywords on the same "level" can really help in reading the code.

Comment: I'm not saying there's no way, I'm just saying that I don't know of any package that does it currently.  I think usually people rely on indentation for that.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Of course indentation is a helper too. I just feel such a highlighting is visually easier. Thank you anyway.